# Extract numbers from a figure

Tags: graphs

I'm looking for a program that can extract the underlying numbers from a figure.

For example, from the graph

[image]

it could extract the underlying data:

```
1   10
2   20
3   40
4   60
5   100
6   150
7   200
8   260
9   350
10  450
```

If possible, free, open source, works on Windows 7 and supports other type of graphs, such as:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [Datathief III](http://www.datathief.org/) for a few years. It is a shareware java app that can extract data from an image. It works best on line graphs, but you can use it on any type of data with two axes (that excludes pie charts). All you need is define three reference points on the axes `(0,0)`, `(12,0)`, and `(0,500)` in your first image, then you are ready to go.

It has two modes, **trace** and **points**. **Trace** automatically captures data by following the color of the selected line, whereas **points**  allows you to place points manually.

Using **trace** mode requires defining the start and end points of the data, as well as the line color. Here is an example:

[image: trace mode]

Using **points** mode is better when you have a specific set of points:

[image: points mode]

The output here is:

```
1.0213, 9.9231
2.0426, 19.8462
3.0331, 39.5697
3.9931, 57.889
5.0438, 105.6307
5.9877, 151.9594
7.0384, 199.701
8.0277, 258.64
9.0159, 352.5929
10.0193, 450.7492
```

Better accuracy can be achieved with further fine tuning.

---

**Summary**

[Datathief](http://www.datathief.org/)

Pros:

- Fast and accurate
- Traces data automatically, and allows for manual adjustments

Cons:

- Does not support pie graphs
- Shareware - not open source

Answer (score 0):

Another very good option is the [Engauge Digitizer](http://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/).

> The Engauge Digitizer tool accepts image files (like PNG, JPEG and TIFF) containing graphs, and recovers the data points from those graphs. The resulting data points are usually used as input to other software applications. Conceptually, Engauge Digitizer is the opposite of a graphing tool that converts data points to graphs. The process is shown below - an image file is imported, digitized within Engauge, and exported as a table of numeric data to a text file. Work can be saved into an Engauge DIG file.