# Simple tool for drawing plots to be output as a table of numbers

Tags: gui, graphs, command-line, plain-text

I want a program for inputting a function defined by table of values in GUI.

[feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) can turn a set of text lines with numbers into a graph in one move. I want to do the reverse - turn a graph I edited in GUI into a table of numbers.

Expected workflow is something like this:

[image: drawgraph sketch]

```
$ drawgraph
-3.2 2
-2.8 3
-2.5 7
-1.7 11
-1.1 9
-1 -9
-0.3 -7
0.2 -4
1.1 9
1.5 9
2 5
$
```

Additional features:

- Inputting the plot to be edited instead of creating one from scratch;
- Editing the plot not just point by point, but also with a "brush";
- Support of more than one plot;
- Logarithmical scale support;
- Subdividing, merging, optimizing;
- Applying transforms like smoothing or editing spectrum like in equalizer, adding noise, etc.;

Graphics and audio editors often have such function editor embedded, for example for "curves" tool. I want it standalone.

Comment: Related but different: [Extract numbers from a figure](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10749/903)